# Javascript - Make image appear at cursor

Tags: javascript, html

Any ideas how to achieve an effect similar to this?

http://garyc.me/fun/gusta.swf

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is not Yahoo Answers...Post some relevant code if you want solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the `mousemove` event

http://jsfiddle.net/GTTGD/1/

```
var img = new Image;
img.src = 'http://files.myopera.com/lengoc89/albums/317185/3133~Kitty-Posters.jpg';

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var tag = document.createElement('img');
    console.log(e);
    tag.src = img.src;
    tag.style.position = 'absolute';
    tag.style.height = '50px';
    tag.style.width = '50px';
    tag.style.top = (e.pageY || e.clientY) + 'px';
    tag.style.left = (e.pageX || e.clientX) + 'px';
    this.body.appendChild(tag);
}, false);​
```

Answer (score 0):

In hindsight, that was a pretty stupid answer. So I will answer again with an actual example of a way to make what's in that flash file in HTML5.

If you can fully understand how this works, making the same thing in flash should be no sweat. But also consider that the demo I made unintentionally runs faster and more stable than the flash demo, so you might consider using HTML5 for your next project.

The example I made is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sTycT/2), and without further ado, I will break it down line by line, starting with the HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas. <br>
    Get or upgrade to a modern browser like Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox.
</canvas>
```

This creates a `<canvas>` element in the DOM. The canvas is a 2D (and soon 3D!) graphics API included in the HTML5 spec that allows the drawing and animating of graphics. You use `JavaScript` to control the canvas through its `drawing context`, and thus a good knowledge of `ECMAscript` (Which includes `JavaScript` and Flash's `ActionScript`, which is based on `JavaScript`) will help immensely.

Now the JavaScript:

```
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

This gets the drawing context, which provides the methods that allow you to draw on the canvas. Currently the only parameter is `'2d'`, however there is a parameter `'experimental-webgl'` that allows the use of an experimental 3D technology called `web gl`, but requires a good video card. I believe this is only available in Webkit browsers like Google Chrome and Gecko browsers like Firefox.

Note: In every browser I've ever tested, you don't have to use the `document.getElementById()` method to grab an item by its id. As long as the id is present in the HTML, a list of variables containing and named after the id of each element with that attribute is made `on load`. Of course, this means that you HAVE to put the `<script>` tag below the HTML, not above it, so the DOM and node lists can be loaded beforehand.

```
mouse = [0,0];
imgLoaded = false;
trail = [];
```

These variables are used to track the mouse position, whether the image has been loaded, the trail, and the size of the image. `mouse` is an array that holds the X and Y coordinates of the mouse, and is updated every time the mouse moves, `imgLoaded` is set to true in a later function to indicate the image has been loaded so it properly draws, `trail` is an array which holds every mouse position since the demo started, it holds arrays which have coordinates used to draw the trail, and is updated along with `mouse`.

```
img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    imgLoaded = true;
};
img.src = 'http://images.encyclopediadramatica.se/0/0a/Me_gusta_original.png';
```

This block of code creates an image, sets its source to a reliable server holding the Me Gusta Picture, and instead of drawing the picture `on load`, it updates the `imgLoaded` boolean to indicate that the image can now be drawn.

```
canvas.onmousemove=function(e){
    var X,Y;
    if(e.clientX){
        X = e.clientX;
        Y = e.clientY;
    }else{
        X = e.pageX;
        Y = e.pageY;
    }
    mouse = [X,Y];
    trail.push(mouse);
};
```

This event function (a special type of function that runs on an event) is bound to the canvas, and when it runs, it grabs the mouse's position from the `e` variable that has been passed into the arguments. After doing this, it adds the coordinates to the `trail` array.

```
UPDATE = function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    if(imgLoaded){
        for(var i = trail.length-50;i<trail.length;i++){
            if(trail[i]){
                ctx.drawImage(img,trail[i][0],trail[i][1],100,100);
            }
        }
    }
    setTimeout(UPDATE,1000/60);
};
UPDATE();
```

This is where the rest is handled. The function is defined and then run immediately after, and after the function completes, it runs itself again with a delay of `1000/60` milliseconds, or at 60 fps. Now we actually get to see some canvas action!

`ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height)` clears the entire canvas of everything that is drawn on it

It now checks if the image is loaded by requesting the `imgLoaded` variable. If true, it continues on to loop through the trail object and draws the image for every coordinate. However, something pretty clever happens here. Instead of starting `i` at 0, I started it at `trail.length-50`, and ended it at `trail.length`, because in practice, we only want to display a segment of the array, not the entire thing.

Since the array starts out empty, it checks if a boolean expression `trail[i]` returns true. If it does, then it proceeds to draw that part of the trail. If not, then it bypasses it, avoiding errors as well. After the loop, it finishes off by running itself again.

As for how I hid the cursor and got the dotted border, that's CSS, or Cascading Style Sheets. The language that allows for precise control of the styling of a page and what give this very site its pazzaz.

I hope this helps more than the previous answer I gave, which is below this line:

---

`Before reading: I apologize if it seems like I misinterpreted the question. The question is about how to detect mouse events and this works as a great beginner example to demonstrate mouse events.`

in javascript, there are several ways to go about making an image appear when you hover over it, one nice, easy example is:

HTML:

```
    <div id="img">
    i am a placeholder
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
    var img = document.getElementById('img')
    var Main = {
    IN: function() {
        img.innerHTML = '<img src="img.jpg"></img>'
    },
    OUT: function() {
        img.innerHTML = 'I am a placeholder'
    }

    }
    //I used an object to hold the functions and keep them uniform

    img.onmouseover = Main.IN
    img.onmouseout = Main.OUT​
    //these events call the function
```